# Search OLDEST date in a log file

Tags: date, search, batch-file

I have a log.txt file which contains DATE occurrence as in below format for last 1 year data.

```
25/11/2013
```

How we can echo the oldest date in log.txt file ?

My below search on google and Stack ended with files only, didn't get anything regarding inside file's content.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/o-d/t:c') do set OLD=%%i
echo The most oldest file is %OLD%
```

**Log snippet:**

```
SERVERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
APPNAME          TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('0 TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('0
-------------------- ------------------- -------------------
STRDESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUSERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Windows64
Metadata         25/11/2013 14:14:41 25/11/2013 14:25:29

user@DBgroup
```

[image: log snap]

Comment: Do you want one line or a record of entries as the result?  What would you like as the result?

Comment: @foxidrive...Only one line is required as result: echoing the oldest date.

Comment: It's allready not clear. It's complicate to give a part of your log file with the dates, as exemple ? I Allready don't now if the dates to check are on the same line, if the two dates on your line are always the same, that we can check just the first..... Give an snippet that represente your problem.

Comment: It's a log-file. I would expect, that the first occurance of an date would be the oldest?

Comment: @sachadee..I have attached the log image above.

Comment: @Stephan..unfortunately, thats not the case..please see attached log image above.

Comment: OK check the Edit of my first code. It should work like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution :

EDIT :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type sacha.txt ^| findstr /i "./"') do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (set $test=%%b
                       if "!$test:~2,1!"=="/" (set $date=%%b
                               set #!$date:~6,4!!$date:~3,2!!$date:~0,2!=%%b)))

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set #') do (echo The Oldest Date Is : %%a
                                                exit /b)
endlocal
```

Apparently your date is always the third word of the line containing the date. If that the case you can use this CODE below if you dont't now if it's always the case use the one above, who test if the third char of the words in the line is an "/" if yes it set the word as date. But both work with the snippet you gave. The first one give you just more security. But i think the second is OK and faster :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type sacha.txt ^| findstr /i "./"') do (
  for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%b in ('echo %%a') do set #!$date:~6,4!!$date:~3,2!!$date:~0,2!=%%b)

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set #') do (echo The Oldest Date Is : %%a
                                                exit /b)
endlocal
```

Comment: @Sachadee..I've put the log snippet above [ which has `dotted lines (----)` ] for which its not working.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need `delayed expansion` here:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /F "tokens=1-3delims=/" %%a IN (log.txt) DO set "$%%c%%b%%a=%%a/%%b/%%c"
FOR /F "tokens=2delims==" %%A IN ('set $') DO if not defined OldestDate set "OldestDate=%%A"
ECHO(The most oldest file is %OldestDate%
```

Comment: @Endoro.. I don't know why but its not giving the result .I've put the log snippet above for your reference [ there are **dotted lines (----)** in log].

Comment: @Endoro..As being fan of your simplified batch methods..I am still desperately interested to know how it'll give the correct result ? :)

Comment: @Sunny you uploaded a log file to RS and I looked into it. Just replace the first part of my first `for` loop with the code by foxidrive: `for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in (' find "/" ^< "log.txt" ') do`.

Answer (score 1):

See how this goes, sunny:

```
@echo off
del tmp.tmp 2>nul
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in (' find "/" ^< "log.txt" ') do >>tmp.tmp echo %%c/%%b/%%a
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sort /r ^<tmp.tmp ') do set lastdate=%%a
echo "%lastdate%"
pause
del tmp.tmp 2>nul
```

Comment: @Foxi..now we are close to result..Its giving the NEWEST DATE.

Comment: I confused myself while testing it.  Try it now.